# How to get user_meta value for new user regsitered?

Tags: meta-value

We have a customized the registration process. Users register themselves. When a user registers, some meta values are updated based on the `$user_id`. Now we need to send an email.

We have used action hook named `user_register` to send the email. When a user registers, an email will be sent to that user. The problem is that the meta value is not being sent even when I have gave the hook a priority of 100.

How can I fetch the meta value of that particular user using `user_register` hook so i can send them in an email?

Here's the registration code:

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'sendMailM', 99999, 1 );
function sendMailM( $user_id ) { 
    $title  = "Title";
    $from   = "noreply@admin.no";

    global $wpdb, 
        $password;

    $user       = new WP_User( $user_id );
    $user_login = stripslashes( $user->user_login );
    $user_email = stripslashes( $user->user_email );
    $companyCreatedUserP4 = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'companyId', true );

    if( ! empty( $companyCreatedUserP4 ) )
    {
        $current_companyP4  = new WP_User( $companyCreatedUserP4 );
        $companyEmailP4     = $current_companyP4->user_email;
        $messageAdmin       = 'New User ' . $user_login . ' is registered on your site under ' . $current_companyP4->user_firstname . ' company.';
        $messageCompanyP4   = 'A new user with a user name: ' . $user_login . ' was registered under your company.';
    }
    else
    {
        $messageAdmin = 'New User ' . $user_login . ' is registered on your site.'; 
    }

    $message  = "<p>You are now registered . Your user name and password are included in this email. </p>";
    $message .= "<p>" . sprintf( __( 'Username: %s' ), $user_login ) . "\r\n\r\n</p>";
    $message .= "<p>" . sprintf( __( 'Password: %s' ), $passwor d) . "\r\n</p>";

    $headers = 'From: ' . $title . '<' . $from . ">\r\nReply-To: " . $from;
    add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', create_function( '', 'return "text/html";' ) );
    wp_mail( get_option( 'admin_email' ), 'New User Registration ', $messageAdmin, $headers );  /*admin*/

    if( ! empty( $companyEmailP4 ) )
        wp_mail( $companyEmailP4, 'New User Registration ', $messageCompanyP4, $headers );      /*user*/
}
```

This is the code to create a new user and update the meta value:

```
$user = wp_insert_user( $userdata );
update_user_meta( $user, 'companyId', 350 );
```

Comment: Are you using the [`get_user_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta) function? Looks like the `$user_id` gets passed to the [`user_register`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register) hook

Comment: Yes.I am using get_user_meta(). `$companyCreatedUserP4 = get_user_meta($user_id, 'key', true );`

Comment: but result was empty, but it should not be...When i pass static previously created user id, then i am getting the result.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you're using the correct key name? Did you look in the database to verify?

Comment: yup.. 100% sure. I have verified db even..I am stucked with this since last 8 working hours

Comment: If that's the case then you need to edit your original question ( using the `edit` button above ) and add the code that **adds** the user meta and the code where you're trying to retrieve the user_meta, otherwise there's not much anyone can do to help with the information given.

Comment: What i think is that, when user_register action hook run, at that time no meta_value were updated in a db.

Comment: That could be but without knowing how the user meta is being saved nobody can give a better solution...

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Plz go through this code. is there any thing wrong in execution order?

Comment: Where are you running the `wp_insert_user()` function? Where are you running the `update_user_meta()` function? That's the important part. I'm pretty sure user registration already does `wp_insert_user()` why are you running it again?

Comment: `wp_insert_user()` and `update_user_meta()`  both the functions are running on submiiting the registration form.
`if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$userdata = array(
        'user_login'    =>   $email,
        'user_email'    =>   $email,
        'user_pass'     =>   $password,
        'first_name'    =>   $first_name,
        'last_name'     =>   $last_name,
  'role'   => $userrole, 
        );
  $user = wp_insert_user( $userdata );
  update_user_meta($user,'companyId',350);
}`

Comment: I've edited your question and so it's easier to understand and the code is easier to read. Please try not to put code blocks in the comments here, instead edit your question and add in that code as more detail explaining what it is and why it's important. Also, when adding code to questions there's a button which looks like this `{}` - highlight your code and click that button and it will put it into a nice code block as you see now. This makes it much easier for people to read and for other to help you. I think I have a solution to your problem, I'm writing up an answer now just give me a sec

Comment: so sorry for the mistakes done by me for posting.
Btw Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read de Codex entry for [`user_register` action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register), it says:

> Not all user meta data has been stored in the database when this
>   action is triggered.

Note that doing:

```
$user = wp_insert_user( $userdata );
update_user_meta( $user, 'companyId', 350 );
```

Follow this sequence: insert user -> run `user_register` action -> rung your update user meta function. So, your custom user meta is not available in `user_register` action.

So, instead of updating user meta data after `wp_insert_user()`, you could do it inside the `user_register` action:

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'sendMailM' );
function sendMailM( $user_id ) {

    // Note: $_POST data is available here,
    // just in case you need to update user meta based on form input,
    // for example, $_POST['companyId']
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'companyId', 350 );

    $title  = "Title";
    $from   = "noreply@admin.no";

    global $wpdb, 
        $password;

    $user       = new WP_User( $user_id );
    $user_login = stripslashes( $user->user_login );
    $user_email = stripslashes( $user->user_email );
    // You can now access to previously updated user meta
    // Or get the companyId directly from $_POST input if needed
    $companyCreatedUserP4 = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'companyId', true );

    if( ! empty( $companyCreatedUserP4 ) )
    {
        $current_companyP4  = new WP_User( $companyCreatedUserP4 );
        $companyEmailP4     = $current_companyP4->user_email;
        $messageAdmin       = 'New User ' . $user_login . ' is registered on your site under ' . $current_companyP4->user_firstname . ' company.';
        $messageCompanyP4   = 'A new user with a user name: ' . $user_login . ' was registered under your company.';
    }
    else
    {
        $messageAdmin = 'New User ' . $user_login . ' is registered on your site.'; 
    }

    $message  = "<p>You are now registered . Your user name and password are included in this email. </p>";
    $message .= "<p>" . sprintf( __( 'Username: %s' ), $user_login ) . "\r\n\r\n</p>";
    $message .= "<p>" . sprintf( __( 'Password: %s' ), $passwor d) . "\r\n</p>";

    $headers = 'From: ' . $title . '<' . $from . ">\r\nReply-To: " . $from;
    add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', create_function( '', 'return "text/html";' ) );
    wp_mail( get_option( 'admin_email' ), 'New User Registration ', $messageAdmin, $headers );  /*admin*/

    if( ! empty( $companyEmailP4 ) )
        wp_mail( $companyEmailP4, 'New User Registration ', $messageCompanyP4, $headers );      /*user*/
}
```